# Maximum available shared memory for boost shared memory allocation

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory

How to check the maximum available shared memory that 'managed_shared_memory' allocate? (boost)

I am trying to allocate all 32 GB of available memory on an octacore machine and its not allowing me to do so.

Is there any OS requirement I need to fullfill or set some permissions to do so.

Is there any way I can get the size available to me from OS.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the BOOST implementation, but I would have thouught that a 32GB shared memory would be doable (subject to available memory and address range, etc). I take it you definitely have 32GB of free memory in a contiguous address range? How much physical RAM do you have? And from the department for silly questions, you are compiling for 64-bit, right?

Comment: Yes 64bit, ram is 64GB and available shared memory is 32GB.

Answer (score 0):

It depends in which OS you are using.

As example, in Linux OS, there is a function the deals with this kind of information: `getrlimit`

From this man page you can read this (one of those resources is):

> RLIMIT_DATA This is the maximum size of a process' data segment, in bytes. If this limit is exceeded, the malloc() function shall fail with errno set to [ENOMEM].